# Demux: How to deserialize transaction data from MongoActionReader stored in MongoDB by mongo_db_plugin?

Tags: eosjs

When I use NodeosActionReader I can get data passed as parametters to actions via payload.data.parametter. However when I use MongoActionReader payload.data contains only hex data. How to deserialize this data back to the the parametters which were passed to action?